# division incrementor in a for loop?

Tags: c#, .net

Basic question here, just got curious about coding a simple formula out, and wanted to know if it's possible to use a division operator for the increment in a c# for loop?

Using int X, would like to divide X repeatedly by some number Y until X <= some number Z.

for ( x = 0; x <= Z; X/Y) ? // Here, I throw an error at X/Y, also with (X/Y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `x = x / y`. `x/y` does nothing useful on it's own and, while it's at least valid syntax in C and C++, I'm not sure C# will not allow it.

But you should keep in mind that you have your condition "bass-ackward" <sup>(a)</sup> :-) This condition must be satisfied for the loop to *continue,* not to terminate.

So, if you mean (as you state) "... *until* X <= some number Z", the loop should be:

```
for (x = 0; x > Z; x = x / Y)
```

In any case, since `x` starts at zero, and zero divided by anything (except zero) is *still* zero, the value of `x` will never change. I suspect you meant to start `x` at some larger value since you're reducing it with the division operator and you want to terminate when it drops below a certain value.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> To be honest, I'm not sure why this phrase is so popular. It's a corruption of the obvious Spoonerism meaning things are the wrong way around but, as far as my limited knowledge of anatomy goes, I'm pretty certain the a** is *supposed* to be backwards :-)

Answer (score 3):

The last segment in `for` loop is usually meant for changing the loop variable (usually incrementing or decrementing). So, `x++` (which is `x = x + 1`) increments `x`. `x/y` does not change `x` (or `y`, and is not a valid C# statement). you could do `x /= y` which would compile.

Answer (score 2):

/= is the divisional incremental operator.

```
x /= 2;
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
x = x / 2;
```

should be fine to use it.

```
// changing x = 1 in example code, as per discussion below this comment
for (x = 1;x <= z;x /= y) 
{
//whatever
}
```

Comment: there's no way to tell if it's infinite or not, that would depend on what the values for y and z are, which we can't see.  i just took it from his original example.  presumably he'd be setting them to appropriate values and/or doing something additional in the loop code to avoid that.

Comment: Actually the loop is either null or infinite. It's null if `z` is greater than zero. It's infinite if `z` is less than or equal to zero. But that's a fault with the question rather than Cortright's answer.

Comment: ah, yes i see now.  anyway, just copied the asker's code down, but point taken!

Comment: (changed x=0 in my answer to x=1 so as to avoid aforementioned problem)

Answer (score 0):

on increment section, it should be statement. like, x=x/y

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but in addition to what others have pointed out about actually reassigning `x`:

- If `x` starts at `0`, it will never change
- The condition is a continue condition ("while"), not a termination condition ("until")

So you would end up with:

```
for( var x = max_x; x > min_x; x /= y )
```